# Javascript - difference between closure and normal function

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, and i have been going through a video where i found a reference to the fade function (modified to include less code) using closures below.

```
 function fade(id) {
            var dom = id, level = 1;
            console.log(dom + ' : ' + level);
            function step() {
                var h = level.toString(16);
                dom = dom + h;
                if (level < 5) {
                    console.log('level '+ id + ' = '+level);
                    level +=1;
                    setTimeout(step,100);
                }
            }; setTimeout(step,100);
};
```

When i call this function multiple time say fade(1);fade(2);fade(3); in the browser console, i see that the execution is parallel i.e. all the three function calls are being executed simultaneously. I presume it is parallel because of the log statements in the console.

Then i declare step as a function outside the scope of the fade function and make a call from fade to this function:

```
function step(dom, level) {
    var h = level.toString(16);
    dom = dom + h;
    if (level < 5) {
        console.log('level '+ dom + ' = '+level);
        level +=1;
        setTimeout(step(dom,level),100);
    }
};

function fade(id) {
    var dom = id, level = 1;
    console.log(dom + ' : ' + level);
    setTimeout(step(dom,level),100);
};
```

When i call fade like this: fade(1);fade(2);fade(3);  the execution almost seems like sequential i.e. it fade(1) is executed first followed by the others in order.

What is the reason for this behavior, is it because of closure, if so can you please explain what changed when i introduced closure to the top function? Any help regarding this, topics/concepts to look for would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're immediately calling `step(dom,level)` in your second example (rather than waiting), and the function call `step(dom,level)` does not return a function, so it's not a valid thing to pass in to `setTimeout`. You want `step.bind(null, dom, level)`.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling the `step` function to execute instead of passing it as a reference in the 'non-closure' code. Try changing `step()` to `step` in the `setTimeout()` calls

Comment: Thank you, i see what i was doing wrong and has no relation to closures.

Comment: Read JavaScript the good parts. It has a stunning explanation of closure an how it can be used to create private variables

Comment: Will do. Thanks again.